# Where do the QA automation test scripts get executed on pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, ui-automation, selenium-grid

So I have basic knowledge on CI/CD, need of virtual machine for automation testing and integration the VM with jenkins.

Now, my question is I have added the automation test suite bitbucket repository to the CI pipeline. Now when I run the pipeline, I want to know where do the test scripts execute? Do they execute in any remote server?
Now if they execute in any remote server, how do I integrate the remote server in jenkins pipeline to request my pipeline to execute the test scripts in a specific server.

I have requested for a remote server and I have requested for an AD group in which QAs have been added so that the AD gets access to the remote server.

My questions:

1. I want to know where do the test scripts execute?
2. I have requested for 1 windows VM of 4 cores. Can I configure both hub and nodes in the server?Upto how many nodes I can configure. I am aware that only one hub can be there.

I tried to research on the above but I am not getting any specific answer for it. I am getting articles related to Vms. CI/CD pipeline etc.

Comment: Jenkins runs what you've defined on Jenkinsfile, it does not know anything about your remote servers or AD groups so it's fully the responsibility of your scripts and people who manage them. As for selenium grid setup - this is a topic for a separate research for our specific project. And a separate question (probably not even on StackOverflow). To me, your question indicates that you probably don't need a grid yet and have to figure out how to run the CI/CD processes in your environment first. Please have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.